# Show newly added posts since last user login time /date

Tags: loop, customization, users, login

I'm looking for a solution to create a custom loop which will only display the last added/ modified posts since the last user login to the site.

It shouldn't be that complicated doesnt it ?

Comment: Are you already saving user logins? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the posts after a specific time will be done in 2 steps.

1. You need to store the last login time of the user.
2. Changing the query to pull the posts which are **modified** after the above login time.

The below function will store the last login time of the user.

```
// Associating a function to login hook
add_action ( 'wp_login', 'set_last_login' );

function set_last_login ( $login ) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin ( $login );

    // Setting the last login of the user
    update_usermeta ( $user->ID, 'last_login', date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
}
```

Then you need to collect the last login time of the logged in user and modify the query as below.

```
<?php
// Get current user object
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Get the last login time of the user
$last_login_time = get_user_meta ( $current_user->ID, 'last_login', true );

// WP_Query with post modified time
$the_query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'date_query' =>
                        array(
                            'column' => 'post_modified',
                            'after' => $last_login_time,
                        )
                )
            );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php // Start the Loop ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php // Show the output ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: The above code will also work for newly added posts since on adding a new post the `post_modified` time is set same as `post_date` time.

Comment: This is working great, Thank you ! i'm on GMT+2 can you tell me how can i modified the last login time to use it ?

Comment: Can you check by using `current_time ( 'mysql' )` instead of `date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )` in the `set_last_login` function? If that does not work, you can check with `current_time ( 'timestamp' )`.