# Hightlight unread posts or new posts since last login

Tags: posts, login

I have no idea where to start to find something like that. I could try with "visited link" and CSS but but that's not very powerfull.

So do you think I could do something like :

Last visit = 2 days ago (is there something to display that ?)
This post was posted 1h ago

This post is more recent than your last visit (login)
So, highlight it please !

Please, take in consideration that we don't want to use cookies because we use different devices.

Comment: "What do you think?" ... that it's an _interesting question_. What have you tried? What was your research so far? Hint: Read about cookies and how they work in WordPress. Then please come back and refine your question, show your research and what you've tried. Thanks.

Comment: No, cookies is not a good solution. We use different devices. Thanks anyway

Comment: So why didn't you write this into your question? Make an [edit], then show us _all_ your research, requirements and what you have **actually tried**. Thanks.

Comment: I may find something : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/show-newly-added-posts-since-last-user-login-time-date?rq=1